# controlsfx CustomTextField add ImageView click event is often not triggered

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

After adding ImageView, the imageview click event is often not triggered. Clicking ten times may trigger one or two times. I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNqvd.png)

```
<CustomTextField prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="300.0" promptText="搜索" fx:id="fieldSearch">
    <right>
        <ImageView fx:id="imageView">
            <image>
                <Image url="@../static/img/search.png"/>
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </right>
</CustomTextField>
```

```
    @FXML
    public ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                onSearchClick();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onSearchClick(){
        System.out.println("搜索");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
```

in your initialize() method. This makes transparent parts of the image also clickable